# How to allow only certain string values inside a Mongodb array using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm creating a server side application using `Node.js` and `Mongodb`. And i'm using `Mongoose` package to access `MongoDB` database. And, i would want my Mongoose array to only allow certain values to be pushed inside it. For eg. If i have configured my `mongoose` array to support values like `admin`, `user` and `course`, is there any way mongoose forbid pushing of values anything other than `admin`,`user` and `course` into the array ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  somefield: {type: String, enum: ['admin', 'user', 'course'], required: ...} 
  ...
})
```

The `enum` attribute will only allow the mentioned values. You can also set a custom error message to check if the request body contains anything other than these specified fields.

Read more here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Since i wanted an array in that place, i could solve it using `somefield : [{type: String, enum: ['admin', 'user', 'course'], required: ...}]`